# Django: how to create models that are computed from other models?

Tags: django

I have expense and income models. These two models should be the base for other model called balance.

Where

```
balance.income = sum(incomes)
balance.expense = sum(expenses)
balance.rest = sum(incomes) - sum(expenses)
```

How to implement this balance model in Django? The expectation is, whenever income and expense models get new data from user, balance will compute automatically. Below is the implementation I have for those models, but the Balance model need to be revised (here just to give the idea about the structure).

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname

class Balance(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='$')
    income = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    expense = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rest = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    saving = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rest)

class Expense(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    category = models.TextField(default='')
    detail = models.TextField(default='')
    place = models.TextField(default='')
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.detail

class Income(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    detail = models.TextField(default='')
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.detail
```

Comment: You can either override the save method in both models or write a custom post_save signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is by overriding the `.save()` method. Please note that this will be bypassed when saving a model via the command line.

```
class Balance(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='$')
    income = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    expense = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rest = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    saving = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rest)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_incomes = Income.objects.filter(user=self.user).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount_sum']
        user_expenses = Expense.objects.filter(user=self.user).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount_sum']
        self.income = user_incomes
        self.expense = user_expenses
        self.balance = user_incomes - user_expenses
        super(Balance, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I have tried the solution above, it works if I do change things on admin page on the balance data and then save. But, how to access the balance save method from browser script when user add expense and income data through api call?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that exactly, can you clarify a bit?